# dotted underline link style with opacity gradient

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, underline

I would like to underline my links with some kind of dotted gradient from 100% opacity to 0%. I made a screen of what I should look like:

[image: dotted links]

I would do sth like

```
a {
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #007acc;
}
```

but there is no gradient to 0 opacity and the space between the single dots is way too small.

Another question regarding this problem: I have some :before content (the '+') and I don't want the border-bottom to hit that content, as you can see.

Is this even possible or do I have to use a png background?

Jquery would be ok too.

Comment: Gradient borders are possible in WebKit, I suspect you will be able to achieve what you want using help here http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Comment: Thank you for the link, that indeed was what has been used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick example. Don't know if it fits your needs.

```
body{
    background:#111;
}
ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
li{
    margin-left:20px;
    width:200px;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:dotted 2px #99f;
    color:#99f;
    position:relative;
}
li:before{
    content:'+';
    position:absolute;
    left:-15px;
}
li:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:2px;
    width:100%;
    top:100%;
    background:red;
    left:0;

background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(17,17,17,0) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(17,17,17,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(17,17,17,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(17,17,17,0) 0%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(17,17,17,0) 0%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(17,17,17,0) 0%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(17,17,17,0) 0%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00111111', endColorstr='#111111',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KZPbf/

Handy cross browser gradient generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: That's an interesting concept.

Comment: @VinnyFonseca only thing i could think of apart from generating a series of individual dom objects with different background colors. :)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I've been looking for! Interesting concept indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a psuedo element with a linear-gradient background to overlay on top of the border.

```
a {
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #007acc;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  top: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(22, 23, 25, 1) 0%, rgba(22, 23, 25, 0) 100%);
}
```

Your background would probably need to stay the same color but this should do the job. You'll still need vendor prefixes and correct color codes depending on the browsers you're planning to support.